# How does one override default icons used to dislpay uploaded files from within a module instead of a theme?

Tags: 7, theming, hooks

I'm attempting to add a custom icon for file uploads via a module. However, all I'm finding online is advice on using a theme function ([How to change File field icons (without changing core)?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4221/how-to-change-file-field-icons-without-changing-core)). I want this in a module to make it work across various themes. I found file_icon_path, but am not sure how to implement it. How would this be done in a module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would want to do something along these lines:

```
function YOURMODULE_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {

  if (!empty($theme_registry['file_icon']['function'])) {
    $theme_registry['file_icon']['function'] = 'YOURMODULE_file_icon';
  }

}
```

and then create `YOURMODULE_file_icon()` based upon the core `theme_file_icon()`:

```
/**
 * Returns HTML for an image with an appropriate icon for the given file.
 *
 * @param $variables
 *   An associative array containing:
 *   - file: A file object for which to make an icon.
 *   - icon_directory: (optional) A path to a directory of icons to be used for
 *     files. Defaults to the value of the "file_icon_directory" variable.
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
function YOURMODULE_file_icon($variables) {
  $file = $variables['file'];
  $icon_directory = $variables['icon_directory'];

  $mime = check_plain($file->filemime);
  $icon_url = file_icon_url($file, $icon_directory);

  return '<img class="file-icon" alt="" title="' . $mime . '" src="' . $icon_url . '" />';
}
```

and change up either `$icon_directory` to point within your module and include all of the various file type icons there, or do a `switch` or `if` on the `$mime` type and grab them from wherever you want, eg, if it's the special mime type you want, grab them from your module's directory, otherwise, grab them from the core/default directory.

Comment: Being dense here.  If theme_file_icon is a normal theme function, then why the manual registry alter?  Shouldn't a theme registry rescan pick up the override?

Comment: I'm also curios why core builds up the img manually, rather than via theme('image')

Comment: I was curious about your latter comment as well @MPD, but that's what it does, I just copied it verbatim. As for your first, it's my understanding that the scans just pick up theme overrides, eg, THEMENAME_xyzzy(), not MODULENAME_xyzzy(), but I could very well be mistaken and making this far too difficult.

Comment: @Jimajamma, thanks for your help, that seems to be working to register the function, which I can apparently name whatever, but I'll keep that naming convention. Now, I have changed the $icon_directory to my module's icon directory (mymodule/images/icons), but it looks like the file_icon_url() function doesn't like it for some reason and returns no path. What could I be doing wrong now?

Comment: not sure, I'd take a look at the `file_icon_path()` function in the `file.module` and make sure your naming conventions match what it is expecting, both with respect to the path as well as the image filenames.  Most notably make sure your path is prefaced with something along the lines of `drupal_get_path('module', 'YOURMODULE')` and that the icons are in the expected name.ext format.

Comment: @Jimajamma, it was operator error :). I had my icon file named wrong. I needed to add an "-x-" to it. I hate that there are different naming conventions for these files, but I guess there's a reason. Thanks again for your help.