# How to hide the filename in drupal 7 files and add link to icon?

Tags: entities

I would like to know how to hide the filename in Drupal 7 files and add a link to an icon? The default style is awful I would like to change that. 
I am looking for the simplest solution because I just know basic HTML and CSS.
Maybe I can use some module to do that? If somebody can explain me step by step how to do it will be great. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Ran across your question looking for the same answer... This is what I found. I'm at best a novice with Drupal, so I need easy solutions.

There is this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/file_field_icons

There are also some more options/notes here using CSS: [How to change File field icons (without changing core)?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4221/how-to-change-file-field-icons-without-changing-core)

Comment: Thank you for your reply Alison, but I know how to change an icon, I would like to know where I can add code link to the icon and delete/hide the name of the file in CSS. My case is about the linking icon not changing icon. I hope that is clear now :-)